# AMP HTML tag is missing

Tags: amp-html, google-search-console

I am getting this error "A mandatory AMP HTML tag is missing from this document" for the below page in my google search console:

https://suntrics.com/tech-blogs/how-to-change-default-gmail-account/

It's a wordpress site, so I am using plugin for AMP. I have also checked in the validator.ampproject.org and it's failed. Showing me the below code.

"The mandatory attribute '⚡' is missing in tag 'html'"

so I please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Related AMP page of mention URL is : https://suntrics.com/tech-blogs/how-to-change-default-gmail-account/amp/ this one??
This particular page is validated successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The document is not a valid AMP document. Please see

https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/create/basic_markup/?format=websites

The error pertains to the following requirement for your HTML document:

Contain a top-level  tag 
( is accepted as well).

So it doesn't look like the AMP plugin is working correctly.

Comment: I have gone through the link but how do I fix it? It's a wordpress site, so should I create a html like as it's saying in the link and paste in the root folder?

Comment: So Nisard just answered the question in his comment to your question. Basically the URL you were validating is not the corresponding AMP document. The one he provided is. You should be good to go. You were validating your non AMP Wordpress page.